# Why does the program RegFromApp always fail?

Tags: windows, troubleshooting

[RegFromApp](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html) is a nice freeware that stopped getting updates years ago and its owner went AWOL (in the sense of not giving support for this app). But is there a way to salvage it since it has no **direct** competitors?

Its purposes is to launch any software and see how it accesses the registry. Kind of like [Microsoft's Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) only more quick and goal oriented.

Both the 32 and 64-bit versions nowadays always display **"Failed to start with the new selected process. Error code: 299
Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed."**

[image: RegFromApp fails]

Comment: What makes you think it is abandonware? The NirSoft website Blog was last updated October 6 2020, which is only 6 months ago. If Nir Sofer had given up he would probably have posted a statement to that effect and have closed down the contact page. Did you try contacting him? I found him quite helpful in the past.

Comment: The date you mentioned is 1.5 years ago. Also, I didn't say the **website** was abandonedware, only this specific app (2014 as written both in the site and in the app's datestamp). I meant AWOL as in ignoring mail and not having a forum. I've added a clarification.

Answer (score 1):

RegFromApp still works on the latest Windows 10, with 1 caveat.
The option to launch a NEW process from within RegFromApp application gives the error-message as you describe.
(This would take an application update to fix. You can't work around that.)

However attaching RegFromApp to an already running existing process works just fine.
This slightly limits the usability as that means you can't determine what a program writes to the registry when it is launching.

Whether or not that is a showstopper limitation for you is for you to decide.

Comment: It is a showstopper. But even if we put it aside, I tried your suggestion and it never shows any changes. Can you check if it actually works? Possibly it fails without showing any error messages.

Comment: @LWC I occaisonally use the x64 version. For me it works, but WHEN registry changes made by an application are shown in RegFromApp depends highly on the application being monitored. For some it is "on the fly" while for other applications only when that application exists and then all changes made are displayed at once. This has always been the behavior for me. Also before Windows 10.